# How to abbreviate date_select month & year?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`<%= f.date_select :deadline, :order => [:month, :day, :year], class: 'date-select' %>`

Instead of `date_select` showing:

- **December | 22 | 2015**

How can we shorten the month and date:

- **Dec | 22 | 15**

I mean this in terms of the _form not the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten the month names by using the `use_short_month` option, like so:

```
<%= f.date_select :deadline, order: [:month, :day, :year], use_short_month: true, class: 'date-select' %>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Close enough. Thanks for the help!